# How to address Error when I import tensorflow as tf

Tags: tensorflow

I install the tensorflow python3.6 cpu version but when I import tensorflow as tf, it shows import: not authorized `tf' @ error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1028. Is there anyone can help me? My system is ubuntu 16.04

Comment: you have to type python first to start the python interpreter in interactive mode, then import tensorflow

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a conda environment with python 3.6(you can change the python version to suit your needs) using following commands and try installing tensorflow

```
conda create -n <env-name> python=3.6
source activate <env-name>
pip install tensorflow
```

It will resolve your issue

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, I have installed tensorflow in my environment. I did the following in my terminal: 1.source activate tesorflow (I created a environment called tensorflow and I installed tesorflow in it) 2. import tensorflow , then I get the error "error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1028." I don't know why I cannot import anything in my terminal but I can do that in jupyter notebook. Did I do something wrong here? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar issue.

Did you mention which interpreter to use?

You can either add the shebang `#!/usr/bin/env python3` at the beginning of your script or run the script as `python3 script.py`. This fixed the issue for me.